# Cannot install SCCM Application Management Extension

Tags: sccm

After working through the SCCM 2012 SDK documentation on MSDN I'm currently stuck at the point of trying to install an Application Management Extension:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949507

The documentation states that I should call DeploymentTypeExtender.Extend:

```
using DCM = Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.DesiredConfigurationManagement; 

[...]

    ConnectionManagerBase connectionManager = new WqlConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.Connect("SiteServerName");

    DeploymentTypeExtender.Extend(@"C:\RdpTechnology.cmdtx", new  DCM.ConsoleDcmConnection(connectionManager, null), @"\\SiteServerName\root\sms\site_ABC");
```

However all I get back when I make the call is an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlQueryException: The SMS Provider reported an error. ---> System.Management.ManagementException: Generic failure
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Put(PutOptions options)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Put()
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject.Put(ReportProgress progressReport)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject.Put(ReportProgress progressReport)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject.Put()
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.DesiredConfigurationManagement.ConsoleDcmConnection.Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.DesiredConfigurationManagement.IDcmStoreConnection.StoreNewItem(ConfigurationItem item)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.DeploymentTypeExtender.CreateTechnologyBasedConfigurationItem(ZipPackagePart zipPackagePart, IDcmStoreConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.DeploymentTypeExtender.PostDeploymentTypeExtension(String deploymentTypeExtensionFilePath, IDcmStoreConnection connection, String wmiLocation, Boolean comprehensive, Boolean revision)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.DeploymentTypeExtender.Extend(String deploymentTypeExtensionFilePath, IDcmStoreConnection connection, String wmiLocation)
   at RdpTechnology.Build.DeploymentTypeExtenderUtil.Extend(String deploymentTypeExtensionFilePath) in C:\Users\goakley\Documents\SCCM Deployment Type\AppMan\Build\DeploymentTypeExtenderUtil.cs:line 38
   at RdpTechnology.Build.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\goakley\Documents\SCCM Deployment Type\AppMan\Build\Program.cs:line 22
```

Further information shows up in DebugView:

```
[1520] SmsAdminUISnapIn Error: 1 : 
[1520] System.Management.ManagementException\r\nGeneric failure \r\n   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode) 
[1520]    at System.Management.ManagementObject.Put(PutOptions options) 
[1520]    at System.Management.ManagementObject.Put() 
[1520]    at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject.Put(ReportProgress progressReport)\r\nManagementException details:
[1520] instance of SMS_ExtendedStatus
[1520] {
[1520]  Description = "The digest is not valid";
[1520]  ErrorCode = 1078462235;
[1520]  File = "e:\\nts_sccm_release\\sms\\siteserver\\sdk_provider\\smsprov\\sspconfigurationitem.cpp";
[1520]  Line = 2142;
[1520]  Operation = "PutInstance";
[1520]  ParameterInfo = "";
[1520]  ProviderName = "ExtnProv";
[1520]  StatusCode = 2147749889;
[1520] };
[1520] \r\n
```

That suggests to me one of the XML files I bundle in the application management extension I'm trying to install is broken - but it's all copied and pasted straight from MSDN.